# Unable to get value from drop-down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem when i try to recover selected value from drop-down list. If i select 2nd or 3rd drop-down list value code returns first value of drop-down list. My code:

```
 drprdepart.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you binding your Dropdown list inside `IsPostBack`? if not that's why its always getting 1st value selected

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
      {
         // Bind dropdown here
       }
```

and the get the selected value and text using

```
    drprdepart.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
    drprdepart.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
drprdepart.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the working code used in my project,

It will add the details to the Dropdown control:

```
DD_CurrencyCode.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
DD_CurrencyCode.DataTextField = "name";
DD_CurrencyCode.DataValueField = "active_currency_code";
DD_CurrencyCode.DataBind();
```

It will fetch code from the dropdown:

string ddCurrencyCode = DD_CurrencyCode.Text;

Hope the code was useful,please let me know if its works for you.

Comment: drprdepart.DataSource = ObjSetting.ds.Tables["filldepartment"];

            drprdepart.DataTextField = "Department";
            drprdepart.DataValueField = "id";
            drprdepart.DataBind();

Comment: @kumbhanibhavesh yup now your code looks good , and you will get the output if you use drpdepart.Text.(i.e),the the datatextfield,in your case it is department. Please let me know if anything else is required.Thanks..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
drprdepart.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```

Or

```
drprdepart.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

drprdepart.SelectedItem.Value for get the string

if you ind objects into dropdown

(Object Type)drprdepart.SelectedItem will convert selected item into selected object